# can't add Textbox to XAML window

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Just learning UWP.

I was able to add a textbox to the UWP CameraFrames sample a few days ago.
  Image BEFORE shows little what Textbox which I dragged to just below "Sample Title Here".

Today, same window is now black, and textbox won't go where I want.

For both attempts, I started with UWP CameraFrames virgin sample.

BEFORE (when it worked ok)………….
[image]

TODAY (can't add text box)…………..
[image]

Comment: Did you try editing the XAML itself ? It seems your `SplitView` might be the one at fault here.

Comment: Also you have two `StackPanel` as opposed to the first image, was that intended ?

Comment: I don't know what a StackPanel is.  I used the UWP sample.  Why is the BEFORE white and the TODAY black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, being used to .NET, the UWP Textbox dragged from Toolbox was so small, that I had to re-learn where on the new Textbox to click it in order to drag it to where I want.

But that fixed it.

Comment: you should also learn how to edit yourself the xaml, that would save you a lot of time!